# pySerial 2.6 not available on pySerial sourceforge website

Tags: python, pyserial

Does anyone know why the PySerial website states that the documentation is for PySerial 2.6, but you can't go to the Source Forge website that it directs you to and download anything newer than 2.5?

Comment: You can download the 2.6 code from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial (sometimes you have to go all the way to *second* google result).

Comment: If you will notice, I'm not asking where to find 2.6, I'm asking if anyone knows why there is a disconnect between the "official" website for documentation and what is available on the source forge website to which it directs you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can download it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial for sure.....Is that not where you were looking at?

Comment: Silly me, I went to the source forge page that the documentation references on the main page.  I did discover this link in the installation instruction, and on my Google search.  I'm just trying to figure out if someone else has taken over the updates to the product, or if they had a reason to separate where you get your downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I also see that there is some confusion amidst the various links they have from that page. However, I believe that if you look at the SVN Repository link http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=46487 then from there they have another link http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/ and that's where they seem to have the updated code (last changed 5 months ago)